# Convert numpy array of shape (n,1) to shape (n,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert a numpy array of shape (n,1) to (n,). Is it possible to do this without having to iterate over the array?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
>>> x.shape
(1, 3, 1)
>>> np.squeeze(x).shape
(3,)
>>> np.squeeze(x, axis=(2,)).shape
(1, 3)
```

I'm pretty sure you could've found this answer from a Google search . . .